# Could not synchronise with database session on first insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Am working on MQ based application. Application is built on Spring and Hibernate and database is DB2. I get this error:

> Could not synchronise with database session **sql error code -181**

**only when the first message in the queue gets processed and insert to DB**.

Same message works fine on next try/insert. Code snippet below:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveMethod(Entity obj)`
{
    entityManager.persist(obj);
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

DAO.java

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: If you look at error -181 in the DB2 documentation it states this "THE STRING REPRESENTATION OF A DATETIME VALUE IS NOT A VALID DATETIME VALUE".  Something in your code doesn't have a valid datetime representation.  Without seeing more of your code I don't see how we're going to help